# Count words in each line of text file in c++

Tags: c++

I open a txt file using argc, argv, and getline. I did that properly, but now I have to get the number of words per line (the number of lines is not known before) and I must output them in reverse. Meaning from the bottom line to the top line. Any help is appreciated. This code outputs the number of words in the file:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <cstring>
    using namespace std;

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        if(argc < 1){   
            cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << "filename.txt" << endl; 
        }

            ifstream ifile(argv[1]);
            if(ifile.fail()){
            cerr << "Could not open file." << endl;
            return 1;
            }

        int n;
        ifile >> n;
        cout << n;

        int numberOfWords = 0;  
        string line;
        for(int i = 0; i <=  n; i++){
            getline(ifile, line);
            cout << line << endl;
        }



        size_t i;

        if (isalpha(line[0])) {
            numberOfWords++;
        }

        for (i = 1; i < line.length(); i++) {
            if ((isalpha(line[i])) && (!isalpha(line[i-1]))) {
                numberOfWords++;
            }
        }



        cout<<"The number of words in the line is : "<<numberOfWords<<endl;

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: This sounds like homework...  If you have a specific question about an issue your having, update with some code in the body, but stack overflow users won't do your homework for you.  sorry.

Comment: I already did most of it, but I'm having trouble with the word count part. Not asking anyone to do my homework.

Comment: Can you show us the code you've already written please?

Comment: The text file gives n, the number of lines in the file, and then the actual lines. For example:

Comment: 3
Hello World
I have four     words
But I have   five  words

Comment: What is the `int n; ifile >> n` for?

Comment: That gets the number of lines that are in the text file.

Comment: I thought you said the number of lines is not known before...

Comment: I think I meant that it is arbitrary. The first line of the file will be a positive number n and the remaining lines are text and I have to count each word in each line, in reverse order.

Comment: Does "ant5bee" count as two words? Or one? Or zero?

Answer (score 1):

To find the number of words per line you would use `std::getline()` to iterate over each line and use `std::stringstream` to extract each chunk of whitespace-separated input. Then you would iterate over each chunk of input and check to see if each character is alphabetic:

```
int numberOfWords = 0;

for (std::string line, word; std::getline(ifile, line); )
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);

    while (iss >> word)
    {
        bool alpha = true;

        for (char c : word)
            if (!std::isalpha(c)) alpha = false;

        if (alpha) ++numberOfWords;
    }
    std::cout << "Number of words on this line: " << numberOfWords << std::endl;
    numberOfWords = 0;
}
```

Comment: What does the for(char c: piece) do? Is there another way to write that part?

Comment: @user3251244 Sure. Replace it with `for (int i = 0; i < piece.length(); ++i)` where `piece[i]` is equivalent to `c` in my example.

Comment: So would the next line then become  if (!isalpha.at(i)) alpha = false;

Comment: @user3251244 No. It would be `if (!isalpha(piece.at(i))) alpha = false;`.

Comment: The code compiles, but it gives me 0 for the number of words. And I should be getting the number of words in each line, so I'll have multiple outputs.

Comment: Take your time. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: It works! If you have time, can you show me how to do it so that it prints out in opposite order? So the number of words in the last line prints first.

Comment: @user3251244 Is this apart of your assignment as well?

Comment: @user3251244 Make a vector of strings, put each line into the vector. Close the file, open your file as an output file stream. Iterate on the vector in reverse and do the same thing as in your code.

Comment: This wasn't a real assignment, but more of a recommended thing. Thanks for the help. I can finish the rest.

Comment: @user3251244 Glad I could help. Could you accept my answer by clicking the checkmark please. It helps a lot! :)